# convert es6 npm module to es5

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am currently using the application which as es6 implementation using babel+webpack.
My webpack config is following

`
      const webpack = require('webpack');
      const path = require('path');

```
  const DEV = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

  module.exports = {
    bail: !DEV,
    devtool: DEV ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
    target: 'node',
    entry: './src/server/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname,'build/server'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/',
    },
    externals: (context, request, callback) => {
      // Externalize all npm modules.
      if (/^[a-z0-9-][a-z0-9-./]+$/.test(request)) {
        return callback(null, `commonjs ${request}`);
      }
      callback();
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          // exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
        },
        {
           test: /\.js/,
           loader: 'import-glob',
           exclude: /(node_modules)/
        },
        {
          enforce: "pre",
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader'
        }
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(DEV ? 'development' : 'production'),
      }),
    ],
    node: {
      console: false,
      global: false,
      process: false,
      Buffer: false,
      __filename: false,
      __dirname: false,
      setImmediate: false,
    }
  };
```

`One of the module`node-lyft`is implemented in es6 format . when I tried to import the package it gives the es6 error which is`import is not defined`

Comment: Anything under `/node_modules/` is ignored by default. If you want Babel to convert a specific third party module, you can do that by adjusting the `include` or `exclude` options.

Answer (score 0):

webpack can be confusing when you first start working with it. What you need to do is add this to your babel loader

```
options: { presets: ['env'] }
```

and make sure you run

```
 npm install babel-preset-env
```

You need the preset to compile ES2015+ down to ES5

Comment: *"webpack is so weird, yo uneed to add this to your babel loader "* Why do you think this is weird?

Comment: seems like a petty comment but I don't mean adding options to your loader is weird, I just mean that webpack can be confusing when you first start working with it. not really sure why you even bothered to ask though

Comment: I see. It sounded like a complain to me. Either way I don’t think this (alone) solves the OP’s problem. See my comment on the question.

Comment: gotcha, I changed the wording to better reflect what I meant. I personally use gulp these days so I'm not 100% certain either